# Pipes shell's sort command only printing output upon exit

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork

I'm designing my own shell in C but having a really weird issue that, as of now, I've only experienced when piping `sort`.

Whenever I run a pipe with `sort` such as `ls | sort -r` the output is correct but only displays when I exit my shell. I've tried doing my forking/piping different ways, redirecting the pipes' stderror output in case it was somehow getting put in there, etc. and have not been able to solve it.

What's makes this odder is that other pipes commands like `grep` and even `lolcat` seem to work normally. I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me along here. My command execution function is included below.

```
int exec_command(char *command) {
    pid_t pid;

    // Split the arguments
    char *args[LENGTH];
    int i = 0;

    // Gets the first token, tokenizing on ' '
    char *token = strtok(command, " ");
    while (token != NULL && i < LENGTH - 1) { // Ensures we don't go out of bounds
        args[i] = token; // Append it to the args list
        token = strtok(NULL, " "); // Fetch next token
        i++; // Increment our index
    } 
    args[i] = NULL; // Set the element after last to NULL

    // Handles cd
    // Removed for simplicity

    int pipe_index;
    if ((pipe_index = find_pipe(args)) != -1) { // Has a pipe
        // Split the args array into two arrays - left half and right half - based on the pipe
        args[pipe_index] = NULL; // args (left_args) ends at the pipe
        char *right_args[LENGTH];
        for (i = pipe_index + 1; i < LENGTH - 1 && args[i] != NULL; i++)
            right_args[i - pipe_index - 1] = args[i];  // right_args contains everything after the pipe
        right_args[i - pipe_index - 1] = NULL; // end right_args

        int pipefd[3];
        if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) { // Create pipe
            perror("pipe");
            return -1;
        }

        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) { // Create child
            perror("fork");
            return -1;
        }

        if (pid == 0) { // In child
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0) { // Create grandchild
                perror("fork");
                return -1;
            }

            if (pid == 0) { // Grandchild reads from pipe and handles the right-half command
                close(pipefd[1]); // Close unused write end
                dup2(pipefd[0], 0); // Replaces standard input with pipe input
                if(execvp(right_args[0], right_args) == -1)
                    printf("Command failed. Check spelling and arguments\n");
                kill(getpid(), SIGTERM); // Ensure the grandchild is killed
                return 0;
            } else { // Child writes to pipe and handles the left command
                close(pipefd[0]); // Close unused read end
                dup2(pipefd[1], 1); // Replaces standard output with pipe output
                dup2(pipefd[2], 2); // Replaces standard error with pipe error
                if(execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
                    printf("Command failed. Check spelling and arguments\n");
                kill(getpid(), SIGTERM); // Ensure the child is killed
                return 0;
            }
        } else // In parent
            wait(0);

        return 0;
    } // End pipe

    // Executes normal commands, those without a pipe
    // Removed for simplicity

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to close the pipes in the parent process. `sort` can't sort the data until it gets EOF, and that only happens when all processes close the write end.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much! I don't know why my instructor never mentioned that anywhere. Is there some way I can give you points for your answer?

Comment: Also, if I'm sorting a long file sometime my next `current dir$:` comes up in the middle of the sort. I thought `wait(0)` would be enough to prevent this, but it's not. Is there any other way to?

Comment: You're waiting for the child that runs `ls`, not the grandchild that runs `sort`. You should run the last command of the pipeline in the child rather than the grandchild.

Comment: Someone must have taught you about closing the write end, you have the comment `// Close unused write end`. You just forgot that it's also unused in the parent.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much for all the help! My shell works great now